# SketchUp and Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, export, 3d-modelling, sketchup

I use SkethUp for 3d-modelling. I have some problems with exporting the models with images in Unity, the images aren't exported if I use file.skp and are exported, but not displayed if I use file.dae. Does someone know the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unity importer

[https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SketchUpImporter.html#:~:text=To%20import%20a%20SketchUp%20file,view%20inside%20the%20Unity%20Editor.&text=Generate%20back%2Dfacing%20polygons%20in%20Unity](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SketchUpImporter.html#:%7E:text=To%20import%20a%20SketchUp%20file,view%20inside%20the%20Unity%20Editor.&text=Generate%20back%2Dfacing%20polygons%20in%20Unity).

Other way to do this is to export the .obj and the textures files separately, create a new material inside Unity using the textures and attaching it to the object in the scene (you can create a prefab after to have it for later use)

Answer (score 0):

Unpacking the prefab and putting the material with my texture to the materials of that white image is a solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).